# How can I extract certain fields from a text file and output them on one line per record?

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I have the output from an nmap scan in a text file. Records are delimited by `--`. How can I extract certain fields and output them on a single line per record, with fields separated by a delimiter?

Here is a sample of the input file:

```
--
Nmap scan report for mail.mydomain.com (146.221.53.49)
Host is up (0.23s latency).
PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-cert: Subject: commonName=mail.mydomain.com/organizationName=The Company & Co. LLC/stateOrProvinceName=Paris/countryName=FR
| Issuer: commonName=DigiCert Secure Server CA/organizationName=DigiCert Inc/countryName=US
| Public Key type: rsa
| Public Key bits: 2048
| Not valid before: 2013-12-26T00:00:00+00:00
| Not valid after:  2015-01-21T12:00:00+00:00
| MD5:   c528 4a28 4860 0a8c 112c 5f91 b63a 1d82
--
Nmap scan report for www.firstdomain.net (66.103.112.215)
Host is up (0.21s latency).
PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-cert: Subject: commonName=*.firstdomain.net/organizationName=FIRSTDOMAIN Ltd./stateOrProvinceName=Sofia/countryName=RO
| Issuer: commonName=GeoTrust SSL CA - G2/organizationName=GeoTrust Inc./countryName=US
| Public Key type: rsa
| Public Key bits: 2048
| Not valid before: 2014-09-28T23:00:00+00:00
| Not valid after:  2018-09-28T22:59:59+00:00
| MD5:   ad44 e45f f677 14d9 bccf 8198 7002 457e
--
Nmap scan report for owa.second-domain.com.com.rs (156.113.124.14)
Host is up (0.21s latency).
PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-cert: Subject: commonName=owa.second-domain.com.com.rs/organizationName=Second Corporation LP/stateOrProvinceName=Malta/countryName=MT
| Issuer: commonName=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3/organizationName=VeriSign, Inc./countryName=US
| Public Key type: rsa
| Public Key bits: 2048
| Not valid before: 2013-09-04T23:00:00+00:00
| Not valid after:  2014-11-04T23:59:59+00:00
| MD5:   7c54 3427 bc82 f94d 4448 3d19 6700 4fbe
--
```

Expected output:

```
146.221.53.49; mail.mydomain.com; The Company & Co. LLC; Paris; FR; DigiCert Secure Server CA; 2013-12-26; 2015-01-21; c528 4a28 4860 0a8c 112c 5f91 b63a 1d82
66.103.112.215; =*.firstdomain.net; FIRSTDOMAIN Ltd.; Sofia; RO; 2014-09-28; 2018-09-28; ad44 e45f f677 14d9 bccf 8198 7002 457e
```

Comment: Don't parse nmap results by hand. Use [`Nmap::Parser`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Nmap::Parser).

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code design and writing service. You are expected to have tried to solve the problem yourself and to show what you have tried before you can expect any assistance from us. As it stands your question is likely to be voted down and closed as not showing what you have already tried. Just saying you have "worked with sed and awk with regular expressions, but failed" does not show us what you have tried.

Comment: You have the Issuer for the first block but not the second.

Answer (score 0):

As has been said, it is very much frowned upon to simply post a requirement and wait for a kindly soul to do your work for you. But this isn't a very straightforward task, and I believe the [`Nmap::Parser`](https://metacpan.org/module/Nmap::Parser) module expects XML for input, so here is something to get you started.

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use 5.010;
use autodie;

use constant REQUIRED_FIELDS => qw/
    host
    name
    organizationName
    stateOrProvinceName
    countryName
    issuerCommonName
    startDate
    endDate
    MD5
/;

open my $fh, '<', 'nmap.nmap';

my (@data, %item);

while (<$fh>) {

  if (/\A--$/) {
    push @data, { %item } if %item;
    %item = ();
  }
  elsif ( m{Issuer:} ) {
    $item{'issuer'.ucfirst $1} = $2 while m{(\w+)=([^/]+)(?<=\S)}g;
  }
  elsif ( m{Not valid (before|after):\s*([\d-]+)} ) {
    my $key = $1 eq 'before' ? 'startDate' : 'endDate';
    $item{$key} = $2;
  }
  elsif ( m{\ANmap scan report for ([\w.-]+)\s+\(([\d.]+)\)} ) {
    $item{name} = $1;
    $item{host} = $2;
  }
  elsif (m{(MD5):\s*([a-z0-9\s]+(?<=\S))}) {
    $item{MD5} = $2;
  }
  else {
    $item{$1} = $2 while m{(\w+)=([^/]+)(?<=\S)}g;
  }
}
push @data, { %item } if %item;


for my $item (@data) {
  print join('; ', @{$item}{(REQUIRED_FIELDS)}), "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
146.221.53.49; mail.mydomain.com; The Company & Co. LLC; Paris; FR; DigiCert Secure Server CA; 2013-12-26; 2015-01-21; c528 4a28 4860 0a8c 112c 5f91 b63a 1d82
66.103.112.215; www.firstdomain.net; FIRSTDOMAIN Ltd.; Sofia; RO; GeoTrust SSL CA - G2; 2014-09-28; 2018-09-28; ad44 e45f f677 14d9 bccf 8198 7002 457e
156.113.124.14; owa.second-domain.com.com.rs; Second Corporation LP; Malta; MT; VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3; 2013-09-04; 2014-11-04; 7c54 3427 bc82 f94d 4448 3d19 6700 4fbe
```

Comment: Actually, `Nmap::Parser` can also run an nmap scan and parse the resulting output. (This isn't made entirely clear in the description section of the documentation.) That would be far and away my preferred method, but obviously if the OP isn't running nmap him or herself and is just getting a file from somewhere else, there's no choice but to parse it like this.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: I absolutely agree. If there's a half-decent module that does what's required then it should be used, but as you say there may be a place for an independent solution. It seems a shame that `Nmap::Parser` doesn't include a hook to inject data of your own, but then CPAN is full of useful modules that are far from perfect.

Comment: Comments on post respectfull accepted. Borodin thank you so much for the code. It works absolutely fine.